# Calcular likes y dislikes en porcentaje

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando calcular un porcentaje de likes y dislikes. ¿Cómo puedo obtener un valor redondeado? Por ejemplo, quiero calcular 2.000.000 likes, con 364.000 dislikes, pero al calcularlo, obtengo un resultado como 84.602368866328% y quiero tener un resultado como 84%. Este es el código que utilizé, pero, ¿cómo puedo redondearlo?

```
$likesPositivos = $row['likes'];
$dislikes = $row['dislikes']; 
$totalLikes = $likesPositivos + $dislikes;

$porcentagem = ($likesPositivos/$totalLikes) * 100;

echo $porcentagem;
```

Comment: Hay una cosa que se llama documentación, donde hay muchísima información respecto a todo esto... especialmente la de PHP, que lleva años y años y años... Por ejemplo, la de [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la función round, el código te quedaría así:

```
$dislikes = $row['dislikes']; 
$totalLikes = $likesPositivos + $dislikes;

$porcentagem = ($likesPositivos/$totalLikes) * 100;

echo round($porcentagem) ;
```